# Elasticsearch - Repository creation fails (disk quota)

Tags: elasticsearch, boost-filesystem

I have an issue with creation of snapshot repository.

```
PUT _snapshot/test-repo
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "test_repo"
  }
}
```

The reply was this:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason" : "[test-repo] path  is not accessible on master node"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason" : "[test-repo] path  is not accessible on master node",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "i_o_exception",
      "reason" : "Disk quota exceeded"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

In the Elasticsearch.yml the following line is there on each nodes:

```
path.repo: /data/backup
```

The filesystem looks like this:

```
Filesystem               1K-blocks        Used    Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  32639224           0     32639224   0% /dev
tmpfs                     32659088           0     32659088   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     32659088      141196     32517892   1% /run
tmpfs                     32659088           0     32659088   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/sesp-root    204343336     2841068    191052556   2% /
/dev/sdb2                   999320      156228       774280  17% /boot
/dev/sdb1                   613184        6928       606256   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1              11625298376  2905961572   8133382964  27% /usr/sxn
tmpfs                      6531816           0      6531816   0% /run/user/0
boostfs               270947533824 74784425472 196163108352  28% /data/backup
```

This issue happens since the storage size is extended - before that there were no issues with that.

ES version is 7.16.1.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: might be an issue known since some time https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/7.9/cloud-aws-best-practices.html

Comment: That is not the case, while that worküaround is for AWS and we are on local implementation.